# Connecting rails with storage services on a mesos cluster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, service-discovery, mesos, mesosphere

How can I communicate a Rails application with a Postgres DB using Zookeeper, Marathon and Mesos? Obviously I can't hardcode storage locations under database.yml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Task storage on Mesos is currently ephemeral, meaning if you were to run Postgres via Marathon and the task was somehow lost, you would lose your database's data. The Mesos team is currently (as of 2014-08-11) discussing ways to support persistent storage: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-1554

Until Mesos supports persistent storage, you should run your database separate from Mesos and give your Rails app (running on Marathon + Mesos) static credentials to it in "database.yml".

Comment: What about using deimos and docker?, Am I on risk of loosing data as well?

Comment: Rails is a stateless service, which Mesos (including with Deimos + Docker) is well suited to run. Anything that needs to be persisted should be written to your database. You could potentially run a cache like Memcache or Redis on Mesos because a cache's storage is intentionally not used for permanent storage.